# PFQueryTableViewController (parse.com) behaves weirdly when UISearchBar is added as header.

Tags: ios, objective-c, uisearchbar, parse-platform

For some reason, my `PFQueryTableViewController's` table view behaves weirdly when I add a `UISearchBar` as the header. When added, the table view fails to load objects queried from the DB when the app starts up. It displays **`Loading`** without actually displaying any objects. When I pull-to-refresh however, it populates with the objects perfectly. Another problem is the cell dividers (thin gray lines) disappear. Here is the relevant code:

```
- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewStyle)style
{
    self = [super initWithStyle:style];
    if (self) {
        self.parseClassName = @"userListing";
        self.textKey = @"listingName";
        self.pullToRefreshEnabled = YES;
        self.paginationEnabled = YES;
        self.objectsPerPage = 15;
        self.tableView.rowHeight = 60;
        self.locationForQuery = [[PFUser currentUser] objectForKey:@"userLocation"];

        //append the add button and title to the navigation bar
        UIBarButtonItem* addButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemAdd
                                                                                   target:self
                                                                                   action:@selector(addListing)];
        [self.navigationItem setRightBarButtonItem:addButton];
        self.navigationItem.title = @"Listings"; 
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad{
    self.locationSearchBar = [[UISearchBar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, 44)];
    self.locationSearchBar.delegate = self; 
    self.tableView.tableHeaderView = locationSearchBar;
}
```

Let me know what else you need to see.

Answer (score 0):

Figured out the problem. I forgot to call `[super viewDidLoad]` in my overwrite.